# nth-child() for tags like img and a don't work in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to use css selector **:nth-child()** to select nth element of a **img** list, but it just can't work, the same like tag **a**. But when I try tag **p**, it really works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>

        img:nth-child (1) {
            position: absolute;
        }

        a:nth-child(2) {

            background-color: red;
        }

        p:nth-child(1) {
            background-color: red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <p>abc</p>
    <p>abc</p>
    <p>abc</p>
    <a style="background-color: #FF7E00">adwddw</a>
    <a>qwer</a>
    <a>qwer</a>
    <a>qwer</a>
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="1.png" alt="">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="3.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>

        img:nth-child (8) , img:nth-child (9) , img:nth-child (10) img:nth-child (11)  { /* It is not working because img is not first-element, it's from 8th to 11th elements. */
            position: absolute;
        }

        a:nth-child(4) {

            background-color: red;
        }

        p:nth-child(1) {
            background-color: red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <p>abc</p>
    <p>abc</p>
    <p>abc</p>
    <a>adwddw</a>
    <a>qwer</a>
    <a>qwer</a>
    <a>qwer</a>
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="1.png" alt="">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="3.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

THis is not working because elements are not at the position that you specified, see now.

Comment: OMG!You are right.The parameter in **img:nth-child()** is counted from the first child element(whatever it is),not from the first **img**child element.What a stupid mistake I have made.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to nth-of-type. The difference between nth-child and nth-of-type is that nth-of-type selects number n of a specific type. 
Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: Yes,yes,than's just what I want originally.Thanks for the earnest answers of you guys.I am new here and this is a good community.